# Power button flashes and turns everything on but than stops working

Tags: desktop-computer

Every time I click the power button on my PC it flashes and turns everything on, like the CPU fan spins and also my RGB fans and graphics card, but nothing shows up on screen and the light next to my power button doesn’t stay on so I can’t turn it off.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details: What is the make and model of the PC? I assume it is a desktop so is it custom built? What is the make and model of the motherboard and PSU? What OS are you using? Windows or Linux? How long has this problem occurred? If recently, what might have changed between previous working status and now. If you can please provide more details to your question they community can help you solve this issue.

Comment: Try a power reset. Unplug the powercord, then press and hold the powerbutton for 30 seconds to fully drain residual power. Plug the powercord back in, and see if it works again. If not, check all cables. If still not, a hardware component died. Could be RAM, could be something else.